# Why does my dice game skip the most Important lines in the code?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hello I am making a dice game and I have a problem with 2 lines of code.

It skips the the lines and doesn't work and I dont know how I can fix it.

Worked on trying to fix it for 40 minutes now and I can't.

This is the problem I think:

```
if %roll% EQU %dice% goto dicew
if %roll% LSS %dice% goto dicel
```

This is the code:

```
@echo off

:dice
echo: roll the dice if the dice land on the number You guessed On You will get double your money
echo: Put the number you think it will land on 1-6
echo: Type Exit then Enter To Exit
set /p dice=?
if %dice% GTR 6 goto HIGH
if %dice% EQU exit goto Casi
if %dice% EQU Exit goto Casi
set /a roll=(%random% %% 6) + 1
cls
echo What to You want to Bet On Dice
set /p bet=? 
set sprice=%bet%
if %money% LSS %sprice% goto nomoneys
echo %roll%
pause
if %roll% EQU %dice% goto dicew
if %roll% LSS %dice% goto dicel
goto Casi

:dwin
echo win 
pause

:dlose
echo lose
pause 
goto start

:HIGH
echo the Number Cant Be greater Then 6
goto dice

:dwin
cls
echo: Lose %sprice%
echo:
echo: The Pot is %POT%$ That You Can have chance to win for only 25000$
set /a money=money-%sprice%
pause
set /a cbank=cbank+%sprice%
echo you have now %money%$
goto CAS_LOGS
```

Comment: Notwithstanding the fact that you don't have labels, `Casi`, `nomoneys`, and `CAS_LOGS`, you certainly don't have `dicew`, or `dicel`, so those two suspected lines can never work. When you post code here we need to be able to replicate your issue, unfortunately what you've posted is not a [mcve]. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59570383/edit) to provide sufficient information for willing responders to assist you.

Answer (score 2):

For debugging where it is going wrong, I started by commenting out the @ECHO OFF so that I can see what the actual line is that threw the error.

```
REM @echo off
```

[Update] I see in your comment below that you have a huge program. 
In that case, you might want to try adding `@ECHO ON` just before the lines you suspect, and `@ECHO OFF` just after rather than at the top, as I initially suggested. 
As an additional  debug method, try adding print statements after various lines to see if you get there and what your variables are at that point.

Then I ran into several common mistakes. 
When doing comparisons in batch-files, it is generally a good idea to check your variables prior to using them in a comparison to prevent uninitialized variables from crashing your if statement with an error like `3 was unexpected at this time.`

The next error is that %money% is uninitialized which is what caused the previous to be an error.
I ran this to initialize the money pot.

```
SET money=100
```

Next, all of your goto statements have no corresponding labels to go to.

Each `goto :something` needs a corresponding unique `:something` label on another line.

This along with @Toaster's answer should get you most of the way there.

FYI: `GOTO :EOF` will go to End Of File, effectively exiting the script.

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at your `goto`'s and `:labels` you have

```
if %roll% EQU %dice% goto dicew
if %roll% LSS %dice% goto dicel
```

but then the results are

```
:dwin
echo win 
pause
:dlose
echo lose
pause 
goto start
```

so your names are different, making them match will help. You might consider a second `goto start` above the line `:dlose`. Also, the label `:dwin` appears twice for some reason:

```
:dwin
cls
echo: Lose %sprice%
echo:
echo: The Pot is %POT%$ That You Can have chance to win for only 25000$
set /a money=sprice
pause
set /a cbank=sprice
echo you have now %money%$
```

looking at this block it appears to also be code for losing which, but at the bottom is the winning code and there is no way to get there, so what is happening is the money gets subtracted, and then added back the same amount, except I am not sure because there is only one reference to `cbank` so I think you might want it to also be `money`.

Comment: I couldn’t Put all the code The program it’s 1500 lines of code right now so

Comment: I would suggest, based upon the code you've provided @Gloxidia, that a large number of those 1500 lines will need to be rewritten. And Toaster, you should change, `set /a money=money-%sprice%` and `set /a cbank=cbank+%sprice%` to `Set /A money-=sprice` and `Set /A cbank+=sprice` respectively, _as already mentioned in Mofi's first comment_.